# How to prompt user for username and password on start WSL Ubuntu

Tags: authentication, windows-10, ubuntu-18.04, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am aware of functions to set a default user or change password for WSL Ubuntu like in [askubuntu thread here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/931940/unable-to-change-the-root-password-in-windows-10-wsl) or [official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/user-support).

What I'm looking for is when we do `wsl` from a cmd, or click the `Ubuntu 18.04 LTS` from Start Menu, I would like to have the same effect as when SSH into a server, it will ask for name or password. I do not want to automatically sign-in. I figured maybe all I need is to not set any default user, but couldn't find how to do that anywhere.

It seems to do this from a normal Ubuntu distro, I would have to edit it in the Settings > Detail or do it from terminal like [here](https://vitux.com/how-to-enable-disable-automatic-login-in-ubuntu-18-04-lts/) - but that's using *gdm*, I don't think WSL has that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that is not possible in WSL. Although you can add users and switch between them.

[check this out for more info](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/128094-add-remove-list-sudo-users-wsl-linux-distro-windows-10-a.html)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: I'll mark this is the accepted answer though, it doesn't solve the problem (since there's currently no solution). Though it'd be nice if you can add on why exactly that is not possible. in the link it does say about adding and removing users but why cannot have the feature i wanted is missing (at least from my eyes)

Comment: "I'll mark this is the accepted answer though, it doesn't solve the problem" ??

Answer (score 2):

I use a workaround to impose password check for privileged users in WSL.
Had created a normal logins with sudo for me and my son in ubuntu2004. Additionaly
created kind of guest login without any privileges and made this login the default. So, after starting with bash, we both need to do **su - your_login** with usual password check.

Answer (score 0):

This works for WSL2 Debian on Windows 11.

1. Create a special user (e.g. called "login") with no password, no home directory, and a special shell "/usr/bin/slogin".
2. The special shell is a script, made executable (`chmod 755`):

   ```
   #! /bin/sh
   exec sudo /usr/bin/login
   ```
3. Add a line to "/etc/sudoers" to let the special user run "login" without password:

   `login   ALL = NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/login`
4. Finally, make the special user the default user when launching WSL in `/etc/wsl.conf`:

   ```
   [user]
   default = login
   ```

To bypass the "login:" prompt, one could launch `wsl` with the `-u` option to choose the user to be something other than the special user ("login"), or use the `bash` Windows executable.  `bash` can be redirected using a `.bash_profile` for the special user.  But generally if you want to block such workarounds, I think you may have to restrict what Windows executables certain users can run (on Windows side), and do some Windows programming regarding security contexts.

Answer (score 0):

Install vlock

```
sudo apt install vlock
```

Run vlock for first time and give it password.
Then modify ~/.bashrc and enter vlock to the last line.

```
vlock
```

then close and reopen your wsl/terminal to see the result.